# MySQL not returning 0 aggregation rows with Left Join and Group By

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query. But currently i'm struggling to get it to return rows that don't have and data in them with the aggregation.

I thought it would work with the aggregation and group by clause, so if anyone could expalin why that would be great!

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.slug, COUNT(i.area_id) as numItems
FROM `area` `a`
LEFT JOIN `item` `i` ON a.id=i.area_id
WHERE i.date_expired > CURDATE() AND i.live = 1
GROUP BY `a`.`name`
ORDER BY `a`.`name`
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're referencing the item table in your `WHERE` criteria which is off setting the `OUTER JOIN`.  Move that to the `JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.slug, COUNT(i.area_id) as numItems
FROM `area` `a`
LEFT JOIN `item` `i` ON a.id=i.area_id
    AND i.date_expired > CURDATE() AND i.live = 1
GROUP BY `a`.`name`
ORDER BY `a`.`name`
```

Comment: @Jonnny -- np, glad we could help!

Answer (score 1):

you should be filtering on the `ON` clause because you are doing `LEFT JOIN`. eg.

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.slug, COUNT(i.area_id) as numItems
FROM   area a
       LEFT JOIN item i 
          ON a.id = i.area_id AND
             i.date_expired > CURDATE() AND 
             i.live = 1
GROUP BY a.name
ORDER BY a.name
```

the difference between filtering on the `ON` clause and on the `WHERE` clause is that `ON` clause filters the records first before the tables will be joined while the `WHERE` clause filters the records from the result of joined table.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `where` clause undoes the `left join`.  The values of all fields for `i` can be `NULL` when there is no match -- and these get filtered out, because the comparisons are never true.

You can fix this easily by moving the comparisons to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.slug, COUNT(i.area_id) as numItems
FROM `area` `a`
LEFT JOIN `item` `i` ON a.id=i.area_id and
                        i.date_expired > CURDATE() AND i.live = 1
GROUP BY `a`.`name`
ORDER BY `a`.`name`
```